# accessing network drive with php open dir

Tags: apache, networking, service, network-drive, linksys

I have a flash drive(or hdd) connected to Linksys Router and set it up for access without login. Then I setup netword drive at Computer(Windows 7 Proffesional x64). I tried opendir(\192.168.1.1); but i'm getting this error

```
 Warning: opendir(\\192.168.1.1\s2,\\192.168.1.1\s2): The network name cannot be found.       (code: 67) in C:\xampp\htdocs\movies.php on line 4
 Warning: opendir(\\192.168.1.1\s2): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\movies.php on line 4
 Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\movies.php on line 5
```

Then I tried couple of tips at php.net opendir comments, but when i tried to log on apache as my account I'm geeting error :

```
Windows could not start the apache2.4 service on Local Computer Error 1069: The service did not start due to a logon failure.
```

The PHP Code:

```
$path = '\\192.168.1.1\\s2';
$dir = opendir($path);
while($temp = readdir($dir))echo $temp;
```

EDIT : well i made apache to log on an admistrator account that i created specialy for this purpose, but still i'm getting this error:

```
Warning: opendir(\\192.168.1.1\s2\,\\192.168.1.1\s2\): The network name cannot be found. (code: 67) in C:\xampp\htdocs\movies.php on line 4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\192.168.1.1` is invalid address for network share. Have you tried `\\192.168.1.1`?

And in both cases you should escape that `\` and write the address as a proper string with quotation marks.

Also, `\\192.168.1.1` alone is not "a valid folder", you have to specify one of the network shares under this IP address.

That being said, you should use `opendir("\\\\192.168.1.1\\share")`.

Comment: well that is my fault i didn't write it correctly in my question the code is :$path = '\\192.168.1.1\\s2';
 $dir = opendir($path);
 while($temp = readdir($dir)){
  echo $temp;
 }

Comment: You only forgot to escape then. `$path = '\\\\192.168.1.1\\s2';`

Comment: i tried even with the escaped path it doesn't work, i think my problem is that apache can't acces network drives and i can't make apacha service log on with any other user account

Comment: Make a mapped network drive then and access the drive letter, it should work. But I have Apache on Windows here and it worked fine with tests.